# Visual Studio 2019 can't use Azure US gov AD for authentication in project creation?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-gov

Our Azure account is US government.  I'm trying to create a new project in VS 2019 with "work or school accounts" authentication.  Using "Cloud - Single organization", I provide my domain (ex mydomain.onmicrosoft.com).  However it is not able to find my domain because it's looking in microsoftonline.com and not microsoftonline.us (the government domain platform).  The error is:

Invalid domain name.  No domain metadata was found at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/mydomain.onmicrosoft.com/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml'.
Which is happening because it's supposed to use login.microsoftonline.us as opposed to .com

How can I get this to work with US government domain?  I have set the environment to Azure US Government in VS, so I'm not sure where else VS is supposed to look.

Comment: Did you *first* make sure you signed into Azure Government with Visual Studio? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-connect-vs

Comment: Yep, went through that whole article.  My Cloud-Explorer panel shows my account with my subscription, along with my app services, insights, SQL server, etc.  So VS is definitely acknowledging my account.  It just won't allow me to use my domain when I try to set an authentication method for a new web app.  It won't switch to using login.microsoftonline.us

Comment: We believe this is a bug and have our internal teams looking into it now.

Comment: @SteveMichelotti is there any progress on this?  Visual Studio 2019 is still unable to create an identity app for Azure GOV subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response on this. Spoke with the VS team and the feature that does this while creating new projects currently only works with Azure commercial - this new project experience will work with Azure Government later this year.

In the meantime, you can do auth the way you want with Azure Government - you just can't do it via this new project wizard. In fact, in the latest version of VS 2019, if you select the Microsoft Identity platform as your auth provider, it creates a JSON file like this:

```json
{
/*
The following identity settings need to be configured
before the project can be successfully executed.
For more info see https://aka.ms/dotnet-template-ms-identity-platform 
*/
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "qualified.domain.name",
    "TenantId": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
    "ClientId": "11111111-1111-1111-11111111111111111",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

You can just go into the Azure Government portal to create your app registration yourself. Then fill in the values in this json file by changing:

- Instance: https://login.microsoftonline.us
- Domain: your tenant
- TenantId: your Azure Gov tenant
- ClientId: your Azure Gov app registration ClientID